# Understanding the endomorphism algebra End($V$), and an algebra homomorphism $K [X] \to \text{End}(V)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, algebras

This is from page 123 of *Analysis I* by Amann and Escher. I am trying to verify the details of the excerpt below.

**Excerpt:**

> [image]

**My attempt:**

According to my book, in order to show that End($V$) is an algebra, the first thing I have to show is that $\big( \text{End}(V), +, \circ \big)$ is a ring. Looking at the definition of a ring in my text, I have to show that (i) $\big( \text{End}(V), + \big)$ is an Abelian group, (ii) multiplication is associative, and (iii) the distributive law holds.

The first two are automatic since End($V$) is a $K$-vector space, which requires the additive Abelian group, and function composition is associative. That just leaves distributivity. For linear $S, T, U \in \text{End}(V)$ and $v \in V$, we have

\begin{align*}
S \circ (T + U)(v) &= S \big( T(v) + U(v) \big)\\
&= S \big( T(v) \big) + S \big( U(v) \big)\\
&= S \circ T(v) + S \circ U(v)\\
\\
(T + U) \circ S (v) &= (T + U) \big( S(v) \big)\\
&= T \big( S(v) \big) + U \big( S(v) \big)\\
&= T \circ S (v) + U \circ S (v).
\end{align*}

That proves distributivity and therefore the definition of a ring is satisfied.

The second step in proving that End($V$) is an algebra is proving the algebra distributive law. For $\lambda, \mu \in K$, we have

\begin{align*}
S \circ \big( (\lambda T) + (\mu U) \big) (v) &= S \circ (\lambda T)(v) + S \circ (\mu U)(v)\\
&= S \circ T (\lambda v) + S \circ U(\mu v)\\
&= \lambda (S \circ T)(v) + \mu(S \circ U)(v)\\
\\
\big( (\lambda T) + (\mu U) \big) \circ S (v) &= (\lambda T) \circ S(v) + (\mu U) \circ S(v)\\
&= (\lambda T)\big( S(v) \big) + (\mu U)\big( S(v) \big)\\
&= T \big( \lambda S(v) \big) + U \big( \mu S(v) \big)\\
&= T \big( S (\lambda v) \big) + U \big( S( \mu v) \big)\\
&= \lambda T \big( S ( v) \big) + \mu U \big( S(  v) \big)\\
&= \lambda (T \circ S)(v) + \mu (U \circ S)(v).
\end{align*}

That proves (algebra) distributivity, and therefore End($V$) is an algebra. (I think the line $ABx = A(Bx)$ in the excerpt has nothing to do with proving that End($V$) is an algebra; it's just a demonstration of the fact that multiplication in End($V$) is composition of linear maps.)

The last thing we have to do is verify that the function $K [X] \to \text{End}(V)$, $p \mapsto p(A)$ is an algebra homomorphism. (I will omit the work I did trying to show that $K[X]$ is an algebra for brevity. Long story short, it's a ring, and can easily be made into a vector space, and the ring and scalar multiplications play nice with each other.)

If we denote the function in question by $f$, then we are first trying to establish that $f(\lambda p) = \lambda f(p)$ for $\lambda \in K$, and $p \in K[X]$. If $v \in V$, then we have

\begin{align*}
\big( f(\lambda p) \big) (v) &= \big( (\lambda p_0 A^0) + \dots + (\lambda p_k A^k) \big) (v)\\
&= (\lambda p_0 A^0)(v) + \dots + (\lambda p_k A^k)(v)\\
&= \lambda p_0 A^0(v) + \dots + \lambda p_k A^k(v)\\
%&= p_0 A^0(\lambda v) + \dots + p_k A^k (\lambda v)\\
&= \lambda \big( p_0 A^0(v) + \dots + p_k A^k (v) \big)\\
&= \lambda (p_0 A^0 + \dots + p_k A^k) (v)\\
&= \big( \lambda (p_0 A^0 + \dots + p_k A^k) \big) (v)\\
&= \big(\lambda f(p) \big)(v).
\end{align*}

The next thing to establish is that $f(p + q) = f(p) + f(q)$, where $p, q \in K[X]$.

\begin{align*}
\big( f(p + q) \big) (v) &= \Big( \big( (p_0 + q_0)A^0 \big) + \dots + \big( (p_k + q_k)A^k \big) \Big) (v)\\
&= \big( (p_0 + q_0)A^0 \big)(v) + \dots + \big( (p_k + q_k)A^k \big)(v)\\
&= (p_0 + q_0)A^0 (v) + \dots + (p_k + q_k)A^k (v)\\
&= A^0 \big( (p_0 + q_0)v \big) + \dots + A^k \big( (p_k + q_k)v \big)\\
&= A^0 (p_0v + q_0v ) + \dots + A^k (p_kv + q_kv )\\
&= A^0 (p_0v) + A^0 (q_0v) + \dots + A^k (p_kv) + A^k(q_kv)\\
&= A^0 (p_0v) + \dots + A^k (p_kv) + A^0 (q_0v) + \dots + A^k (q_k v)\\
&= p_0 A^0 (v) + \dots + p_k A^k (v) + q_0 A^0 (v) + \dots + q_k A^k (v)\\
&= ( p_0 A^0 + \dots + p_k A^0 + q_0 A^0 + \dots + q_k A^k ) (v)\\
&= \big( f(p) + f(q) \big)(v).
\end{align*}

The last thing to establish is that $f(pq) = f(p)f(q)$.

\begin{align*}
\big( f(p) f(q) \big) (v) &= f(p) \circ f(q) (v)\\
&= (p_0 A^0 + \dots + p_k A^k) \circ (q_0 A^0 + \dots + q_l A^l) (v)\\
&= (p_0 A^0 + \dots + p_k A^k) \big( (q_0 A^0) (v) + \dots + (q_l A^l)(v) \big) \\
&= (p_0 A^0 + \dots + p_k A^k) \big( q_0 A^0 (v) + \dots + q_l A^l(v) \big) \\
&= (p_0 A^0) \big( q_0 A^0 (v) + \dots + q_l A^l(v) \big) + \dots + (p_k A^k) \big( q_0 A^0 (v) + \dots + q_l A^l(v) \big)\\
&= (p_0 A^0) \big( q_0 A^0 (v) \big) + \dots (p_0 A^0) \big( q_l A^l(v) \big) + \dots + (p_k A^k) \big( q_0 A^0 (v) \big) + \dots + (p_k A^k) \big( q_l A^l(v) \big)\\
&= p_0 q_0 A^0 (v) + \dots p_0 q_l A^l (v) + \dots + p_k q_0 A^k (v) + \dots p_k q_l A^{k + l} (v)\\
&= \big( (p_0 A^0 + \dots p_k A^k)(q_0 A^0 + \dots + q_l A^l) \big) (v).
\end{align*}

I *think* the last expression is equal to $\big( f(pq) \big)(v)$ but I'm not 100% sure. I'm not sure how to package it as a discrete convolution in the form $\Big( \sum_n \big( \sum_{j = 0}^n p_j q_{n - j} \big) A^n \Big) (v)$ as my textbook suggests.

**Questions:**

Is this work (at least mostly) correct? How can I rewrite the last bit of my work in the suggested form, as a discrete convolution?

Is there an easier way to see that End($V$) is an algebra, and that the given function is an algebra homomorphism? I ask because this verification seems like an awful lot of work, but maybe that's because I'm still unfamiliar with all the terminology.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: This is fine but it's also a lot of work. Things are much cleaner if you think of $K[X]$ in terms of its universal property: it's the free $K$-algebra on a generator $X$, which says exactly that $K$-algebra homomorphisms $f : K[X] \to R$ from $K[X]$ to any other ring are uniquely and freely determined by what they do to $X$. Of course there's some work to be done in proving that the concrete construction of the polynomial ring actually satisfies this universal property, but once you've done that you only have to reason in terms of the universal property forevermore.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan So basically, I should learn more category theory. If I may ask you, I'm just getting started with Lang's Algebra---is that a decent source to learn these things from this "slick" perspective that you seem to have? Is there a better source? I also have Category Theory in Context by Riehl but that book probably presumes more algebra chops than I currently have.

Comment: I don't know, I worked most of this stuff out in blog posts. The point I'm trying to make, which doesn't require an explicit appreciation of category theory, is that polynomials are defined in order to make statements like the one you're trying to prove true. If they weren't true then the polynomials you're working with aren't the right polynomials.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Okay. I guess I'll just try to keep universal properties in mind then. Thanks for your help.